# Кто такой фарар?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, заимствования

Из "Похождений бравого солдата Швейка":

*Вршовицкий **фарар** ещё спал и, когда его разбудили, начал браниться, решив спросонок, что его зовут с требой.*

Comment: Удивительное, вправду, дельце (никак не ожидала!): задать вопрос, получить два плюсика, получить два правильных (менее или более) ответа, ни одного из них не поддержать, выбрать лучшим ответом свой собственный... Пыф! Пы-фы...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: ну Рим, ну правда мне мой ответ нравится, его даже никто не поощрил, а другие ответы не о том. Спасибо за внимание к вопросу и за то, что отвечали, но мне честно мой ответ нравится, а ваши не очень.

Comment: Я, кстати, двух баллов за принятие и не получил, так что это не ради какой-то выгоды совсем. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Вршовицкий фарар{70} ещё спал и, когда его разбудили, начал браниться, решив спросонок, что его зовут с требой. [[ссылка](https://kniga-online.com/books/yumor/yumoristicheskaya-proza/page-27-226136-yaroslav-gashek-pohozhdeniya-bravogo-soldata-shveika.html?__cf_chl_tk=9i_1oiabl9RInegXClhSqP5xhi0d2ig1YZMoD0IC6QM-1694804251-0-gaNycGzNDJA)]

• *Решив спросонок* — во всех изданиях деепричастный оборот обособлен (то есть перед "решив" имеется запятая).

•• Здесь же (стр. 161):

> 70
> Фарар (искаж. нем.) — приходский священник в Чехии и Словакии.

В [другом](https://knizhnik.org/jaroslav-gashek/pohozhdenija-bravogo-soldata-shvejka/28) издании:

> Вршовицкий фарар [Фарар (*sic*) — приходский священник в Чехии и Словакии. (*sic*)] еще спал и, когда его разбудили, начал браниться, решив спросонок, что его зовут с требой.

Comment: Да, конечно, запятую пропустил случайно, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Честно скажу, искал по-русски и ничего не нашёл, а теперь загуглил farar и нашёл чешское farář, о котором есть статья в чешской Википедии. Этой статье соответствует русская статья о настоятеле в православных храмах, но а чтобы всё-таки узнать про то, что же это у католиков, я перевёл абзац из чешской статьи на английский и получил вот что:

> A parish priest (from the Latin parrochus; derived from the originally Greek word compound: παρά + οἶκος, Czech meaning: one who is in charge of the surrounding + world) is a person in Christian churches who is in charge of managing the parish and parish services.

Таким образом, это приходской священник в христианских храмах, он заведует делами прихода и служит там.

Comment: «_но а чтобы всё-таки узнать про то, что же это у католиков, я перевёл абзац из чешской статьи на английский…_» === А почему с чешского на русский не попытались перевести? 

Comment: @Слава: так на русский, говорят, автоматические переводчики плохо переводят. Вроде я и сам замечал.

Answer (score 2):

Из книги Ильи Эренбурга:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же трактует это слово и онлайн-переводчик:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы, Слава, тоже удивительный участник. Четыре месяца на сайте, 30 ответов и неплохой рейтинг (Вас многие поддерживают: 537 баллов — на сегодня). А чего ж Вы-то практически никого не оцениваете (всего — 11 плюсов)? Ну... Раз "задавальщик" не посчитал нужным "заценить", то я поощрю...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: «_А чего ж Вы-то практически никого не оцениваете (всего — 11 плюсов)?_» === По-моему, уже 12. Может, это и мало. Но, думается, значительно хуже недооценки чьих-либо ответов их переоценка: к сожалению, очень многие неправильные, на мой взгляд, ответы получают на этом сайте положительные оценки и отправляются затем засорять своей неправильностью интернет…

Comment: @Слава Да, но уже стало меньше неправильных. Участники становятся умнее. Оставляйте комментарий-опровержение, как советовал модератор.

Answer (score 0):

Комментарий к другому вопросу: *Хотелось бы дообсудить вообще-то...*
Попробую...

• Для начала заглянем в словари:
[**священник**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/215998) — **служитель церкви**, исполняющий церковные службы и требы (в православии: иерей; в других христианских религиях: ксёндз, кюре, пастор, патер);
**приход** — низшая **церковная организация** в христианской церкви; местность, где живут члены этой организации;
**приходский** — соотносящийся по значению с существительным "приход", связанный с ним, свойственный приходу, характерный для прихода, принадлежащий приходу;
[**прихо́дский**](https://diffc_ru.academic.ru/6621/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) и допустимо **приходско́й**.

•• Потом порассуждаем.

Приходский священник (по определениям) организует работу прихода [из перевода: заведует делами прихода] и служит в церкви прихода [из перевода: служит там].
Ничего нового, если **знать** значения слов "приходский" и "священник", к понятиям не добавилось.

Лучше (грамотнее) использовать все-таки слово *прихо́дский*, а не *приходско́й* (как в переводе).

Фарар — так называется приходский служитель церкви **только в Чехии и Словакии**, а не просто в христианских храмах (как в переводе).
Редкое слово. Ну не попало оно в словарь, как, например, кюре (католический приходский священник во Франции, Бельгии и некоторых других странах).

••• Подытожим.

*Фарар — приходский священник* [кто] *в Чехии и Словакии* [где].
Во всех изданиях книги Я. Гашека именно так говорится о фараре.
А объяснений обычных слов ("приходский" и "священник"), если я правильно понимаю, не требовалось...
Да и на отсутствие запятой я обратила внимание...

Comment: Всё же не *приходский,* а *приходской,* по крайней мере в православных кругах первое слово не употребляют. А мне хочется комментария к моему ответному тебе комментарию под вопросом.